# Remote connection to Amazon Instance (Ubuntu) from my Mac

Tags: remote-desktop, amazon-ec2

Is it possible that I can access my Amazon Instance from my Mac? If it's possible, what configuration do i need to set from both computer? and What software do I need to run or install.

I am able to access my Amazon through SSH and FTP. But I prefer managing the server in a GUI interface rather in a command line (SSH)

Answer (score 2):

Given you already have setup SSH and FTP and successfully connected, you should be able to get VNC running. [This post has step by step instructions](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/setting-up-vnc-on-ubuntu-in-the-amazon-ec2-Page-3.html).